# rem samsung curved screen mobile phone css

Tags: css

When rem is used for mobile terminal adaptation, it will fail in samsung curved screen mobile phone, because the actual width obtained is different from the normal width.

So what do we do?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Is this a question based on an assumption, or an issue you’ve encountered? It’s also worth remembering that there is no “*normal width.*”